# ZF1-Doctrine2-ServiceLayer

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, service-layer

Can someone help me understand ["ZF1-Doctrine2-ServiceLayer"](https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZF1-Doctrine2-ServiceLayer) from Guilherme Blanco?

I'm trying to use basic set up to get it running. But the github sample doesn't work for me(I had to use "Service Locator Configuration" from serviceLocator.ini and not from "application.ini" now it seems to initialize properly). I cant find any notes about how to use it. Probably silly question, but how exactly should I get the service in the controller? Something like this?

```
SomeController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function someAction ()
    {
       $serviceLocator = Zend_Registry::get('serviceLocator');
       $serviceLocator->getService('TestService');
    }
}
```

I'm getting Exception  "Unable to locate service 'TestService'".

Can someone provide a little guide on the service logic of this solution please? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you much with that implementation, however, the principe of such architecture is to separate and abstract persistance layer. From a *"stupid"* point of view, Service Locator (ie Dependancy Injection) has nothing to do with the principe of a Service Layer. Both serve different purpose. Service Locator (DiC) helps you to retrieve an Object (it can be a Service, a Configuration object, or anything you want) from anywhere in your application.

I'm not a fan of this static implementation of the Service Locator, where I'd rather use an action helper.

---

But well this exception is throwed because you're trying to get an inexistant 'TestService'.

ServiceLocator usually works with a "Container" which sets up the different services.

Make sure your "TestService" is correctly configured in your Container (it can be a PHP class, an INI, an XML or whatever).

Take a look at the other services and try to understand how they work.

Comment: Thanks Boris for your great explanation! Really helped to understand few things.. And as for the exception you were also right, I had to use name specified in services.ini "test" not the name of the class "TestService"